# Track FaceBook usage through facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I understand that you can collate the user's actions using the graph api, such as status updates and comments etc however how would i go about finding the actual behaviour of facebook user such as time spent logged into their account/frequency of logins/time spent viewing peoples photos etc

I have a feeling it might not be possible though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible, and it would create a lot of privacy issues if it were possible.